# entry.delete(-1) Deletes second to last character in a entry field but I need the last. Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

I have a entry widget that when a user clicks a button it executes this code:

```
entry.delete(-1)
```

But it removes the second to last character from the entry widget. I need to remove the last character why is this not working?

Comment: what type of widget is `entry`?

Comment: @MattDMo a entry widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try

```
entry.delete(len(entry.get())-1)
```

and see if that does the trick. This dynamically computes the index of the last character of any string in the Entry widget, and at least on Win7 deletes appropriately, from the right side.

Comment: I have tried that and it did not delete anything. Anyways end means the end so after the last character.

Comment: @cdw100100 what platform are you on? I just tried a very simple Tk problem on Linux using Python 2.7.8, and associating `e.delete(-1)` to an Entry widget `e` actually starting deleting from the left, rather than the end of the entered text...

Comment: I am on windows7 And I want it to delete the last letter on the right.

Comment: If the name of the entry is `entry` the your code is incorrect. `entry.delete(len(entry.get())-1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(len(self.e.get()))
self.e.delete(a-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. Assuming you have used a class. If not do not use self.

```
a=int(len(self.e.get()))
self.e.delete(a-1)
```

Hope it helps!